# How to import datetime from csv python to sql?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to import a datetime string from a csv file using python 3.8 but when running the code the console returns the error:

ValueError: time data '.Device[12].Measure is executing ' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

And the datetime format inside the CSV file is: 2020-12-09 00:00:00.8380

I'm using the code:

```
import os
import shutil
import csv
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=MXESL10739\SQLEXPRESS;'
                      'Database=MITSF_1;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
print ('good connection')
   
fields = []
new = []
path1 = 'C:\\Users\\sguerra\\Desktop\\MITSF1\\Controller 2020-12-09.log'
print ('good')
with open(path1, 'r') as csvfile: 
     # creating a csv reader object 
     csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)   
   
     # extracting each data row one by one 
     for row in csvreader: 
             for col in row:
                         if col.startswith('20'):
                             new.append(col.split(' | '))
df = pd.DataFrame(new,columns = ['column1','column2','column3','Now'])
for row in df.itertuples():
        cursor.execute('''
                   insert into MITSF_1.dbo.Controller ([Column 1] ,[Column 2] ,[Column 3], [Now])
                   VALUES (?,?,?,?)
                   ''',
                   row.column1,
                   row.column2,
                   row.column3,
                   datetime.strptime(row.Now, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date()
                   )
conn.commit()
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Why don't you use pandas `pd.to_datetime()` and why not make a full insert instead of row by row?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that working on the specific line of code that is failing would be more accurate.

I suggest in this case since you are iterating, to use `pd.to_datetime()` which has the very useful parameter `infer_datetime_format` which might come in handy. If you could expand with more information,we might be able to find an even better an answer, but hopefully this will suffice:

```
pd.to_datetime(row.Now,infer_datetime_format=True).date()
```

Comment: Thanks, did you try this fix though? Did it fail?

Comment: It failed, it shows me the error "ParserError: Unknown string format: .Device[12].Measure is executing "

Comment: Therefore it seems the error is coming from the insert rather than the parsing...

Comment: Hello, the problem was that the csv file had 4 decimal digits and SQL in the column only 3, I trimmed it and it worked.Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that the original CSV file got 24 digits for the datetime date, it was needed to trim it to a 23 digit format, this is because in SQL the Column named 'Now' was in 23 digit format.
The procedure is simple, you add the next line:

```
row.Now[:23],
```